# JS bad words counter

Tags: javascript, count

I try to count bad words on a string, but my code always shows 0. What is wrong?

```js
function checkWord(list){
var j = 0;
var badWords = ["war", "bomb"]; //bad word list
 for(var i = 0; i<badWords.lenght; i++){
  if( list.toLowerCase().search(badWords[i])) j++; //check is it bad word in sting if true j+1
 }
return j;
}

console.log(checkWord("sfasdf dgfdfsg sdfsA bomb war"));
```

Always returns: 0 Should be: 2

Comment: lenght != length

Comment: it should be `length` not `lenght` and after changing it I got 2 as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below snapshot, this might help :)

```js
function checkWord(list){
var j = 0;
var badWords = ["war", "bomb"]; //bad word list
 badWords.forEach(word => {
    list.includes(word) && j ++
})
return j
}

console.log(checkWord("sfasdf dgfdfsg sdfsA bomb war"));
```